Will a request header work for authenticating requests to an app server
We have a Blazor/C# web app running on Azure App Server. And we have a second Python web app running on Azure App Server. The only valid calls to the Python web app are from the Blazor web app or from our simple test client.
Is it secure to authenticate calls by putting a guid in the request header for each request and the Python web app looks in the header and if it doesn't find it, returns an unauthorized?
And we will set the Python app to have 2 guids defined (via the Azure Key Vault) and either is good. So we can then switch to #2 and change #1.
Is this secure? Anything special/specific that needs to be done when taking this approach?

You'd better hire a security consultant to help review such. To me, anything not changed over time (since you are using two constant pieces) isn't secure enough.

@LexLi I respect your advice (which I and others have received over the years). But an API key that's a GUID is how Azure BLOB storage authenticates. And I think SendGrid does the same. I don't know if they stuff it in the request header, but it is an API key that can change, but generally doesn't. My only concern here is that no one overloads this server. The data it returns is not private as it's being called to deliver search results and it only returns an array of primary keys. But getting overloaded would be a problem. So anyways, why a bad idea if Microsoft is using this approach?

The tokens provided by Azure or other modern services differ from GUIDs in terms of their composition. Furthermore, these tokens have lifecycles that can be monitored and revoked as needed. This is why these tokens are generally regarded as more secure solutions, as opposed to yours.

Alone, as defined in the question, the answer is No, this is not secure.
There are several ways to improve the security of transactions being sent to your web app:

If the only requests should come from your other app, you can add some ip and/or port level restrictions on traffic to your python app's server.  This depends on the level of accessibility needed on the server on which the python app resides.

Instead of a fixed guid, you could generate a token on the C# side, write to database, use it as your guid, and then validate it on the python side.  Add some rules, like one-time-use, and/or timeouts to your tokens, and you're off to a good start..


These would be a good start.  There are ways to make the security much more robust.

Correct me if I'm wrong but a guid in the request header, if sent over https, is encrypted - isn't it? I believe that's how BASIC authentication works.

you are correct, the header and the payload are both encrypted in https traffic
